# Infinite Cyclic Group of Integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I am new to group theory. While reading about cyclic groups, according to my understanding, A Cyclic group has a generator that generates all other elements by several copies of it. Now coming to set of integers $Z$ with addition as a binary operation, i read that $Z$ is an infinite cyclic group with generators $1$ and $-1$.

But $1$ cannot generate negative integers no matter how many copies are added and analogously for $-1$ which cannot generate positive integers. So does it mean  $1$ generates positive integers and $-1$ generates negative integers? How about generating identity element $0$?

Comment: Note that "generates" is context-dependent in mathematics.  $1$ generates the group $\mathbb{Z}$ but $1$ does not generate the monoid $\mathbb{Z}$ (as in the latter case, the set of non-negative integers is a strictly smaller monoid containing $1$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the group generated by an element or a set of elements allows inverses to be used when composing elements. The generated group always includes the identity, regarded as the composition of nothing.

$-1$ is the inverse of $+1$, so $+1$ *alone* generates *all* of $\mathbb Z$. Likewise, $-1$ alone generates all of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: so you mean to say  $g^n=h$ is equivalent to $(g^{-1})^{-n}=h$ where $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are generators and $h$ is some element in the Group.

Comment: @Umeshshankar Yes. The laws of exponents apply to groups as well.

Comment: ok when we say $g^n=h$ it means $h$ is generated by $n$ copies of $g$ which also means $h$ is generated by $-n$ copies of $g^{-1}$. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @Umeshshankar Yes.

Answer (score 3):

This is one thing that may be a little easier to understand in multiplicative notation.  The cyclic group generated by an element $x$ is $\langle x\rangle=\{x^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$.

In additive it's: $\langle x\rangle=\{n\cdot x:n\in\Bbb Z\}$.

Thus $\langle-1\rangle=\langle1\rangle=\Bbb Z$.